# ios actionsheet from bar button not dismissing when i tap on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I have an actionsheet that is created from an UIBarButtonItem.

The bar button item programmaticly added when a view controller that is in a tab bar controller that is in a nav controller is show

```
- navigation controller
     -tab bar controller
          - view controller (bar button item created in viewdidload and shown in viewwillappear)
```

The actionsheet loads and displays correctly, the problem is to do with how it is dismissed. It dismisses correctly if i tap anywhere within the view but not when I tap on the navigation bar and this means that i can tap the UIBarButtonItem multiple times and actionsheets are created and overlayed.

I know I could do some logic to see if the actionsheet is being displayed and not recreate it and I could also add some logic to viewwilldisappear to manually remove the actionsheet but was wondering why it isn't working out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding some logic to the viewWillDisappear function to hide the actionsheet if it is showing.

I also had to add some other code to the bar button click action so that if tapped once the actionsheet is displayed, another actionsheet isn't overlayed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a `UIActionSheet` being shown from a `UIBarButtonItem` where the sheet wasn't being dismissed when tapping the back button in `UINavigationController`.

I implemented the solution described by @updog

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if ([actionSheet isVisible]) {
        [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The delegate isn't called when `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` is executed, so the index doesn't matter.